# building a websharper application on mono

Tags: msbuild, mono, websharper, xbuild

I'm trying to build a WebSharper application on mono + xbuild and I got to the following error:

```
Error building target WebSharperPrepare: Can't concatenate Item list with other strings where an item list is expected ('/home/ovidiu/work/hmft/src/hmft/hmft.common/obj/Debug/Raw/', '@(IntermediateAssembly->'%(Filename)%(Extension)')'). Use semi colon to separate items.
```

The target description is this one:

```
 <Target Name="WebSharperPrepare">
   <PropertyGroup>
     <RawFolder>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\obj\$(Configuration)\Raw</RawFolder>
     <RawIntermediateAssembly>$(RawFolder)\@(IntermediateAssembly->'%(Filename)%(Extension)')</RawIntermediateAssembly>
     <ProcessedIntermediateAssembly>@(IntermediateAssembly->'%(FullPath)')</ProcessedIntermediateAssembly>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <MakeDir Directories="$(RawFolder)" />
   <ItemGroup>
     <IntermediateAssembly Remove="@(IntermediateAssembly)" />
     <IntermediateAssembly Include="$(RawIntermediateAssembly)" />
   </ItemGroup>
 </Target>
```

Any idea how to work around this issue?

UPDATE: I'm using mono version 3.2.3 and websharper 2.4.85

Thanks!

Comment: Take it to the tracker please - https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issues - I recently built some apps on Mono 3.2.3 + WebSharper 2.5-alpha (soon to be released 2.5). If you can wait till Monday, I'll help to get this working. Or you can try yourself with 2.5-alpha atm. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I can wait until Monday. I've reported the issue here: https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/167/error-in-websharperprepare-target-when Thanks!

Comment: IMHO this feels like a mono bug, so the correct tracker to report to is http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: tovyo already reported this to xamarin https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=15325 There is no response from xamarin so far. Meanwhile I changed the focus to something else but I'll probably get back on this issue a little bit later.

Comment: I'm itching to try this out too...